# Enable Popups chrome browser for protractor test

Tags: selenium, protractor

Protractor creates a brand new Chrome profile every time it runs. So what i want to do it will enable popup for chrome browser every time when protractor test runs.
I don't want to use existing profile.Is there any way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instance of chrome custom profile and it can be passed to capabilities.

```
export const chromeProfile = {
           browserName : 'chrome',
           maxInstances: 1,
           chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                      // mention list of all setting for chrome browser
                      //For example following two lines disable chrome popup
                      'disable-infobars=true',
                      '--disable-popup-blocking'
                        ],
                  prefs: {
                         // disable password popup 
                         'credentials_enable_service': false
                          }
                           }
                              };
```

Comment: i want to enable it

Comment: Use -incognito in place of disable popup